# What are AWS Local Regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-regions

We're looking at DynamoDB disaster recovery and resiliency, the AWS docs mention the concept of a Local Region which I can't find any other mentions of in their documentation portal.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/disaster-recovery-resiliency.html

The only other mention I could find is here:

https://wa.aws.amazon.com/wat.concept.local-region.en.html

Can anyone point out what these are and how to use them? and some documentation links?

Comment: In 2021, the Osaka Local Region, open since 2018, [became a standard AWS region](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-asia-pacific-osaka-region-now-open-to-all-with-three-azs-more-services/). There is [speculation as to why it existed](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/9u90db/so_whats_the_story_behind_osaka_region/), but it does not appear there are any remaining Local Regions.

Comment: This concept seems to have disappeared from AWS documentation but Wayback Machine can be used. For example in 2019: "The Asia Pacific (Osaka) Local Region is a Local Region, which is a new type of region that comprises an isolated, fault-tolerant infrastructure design located within a single datacenter. The Asia Pacific (Osaka) Local Region consists of one Availability Zone and is intended to be used in conjunction with the Asia Pacific (Tokyo) Region. This region requires that customers request access through a sales representative."

Comment: Thanks, did not realise this is a historic concept.